# Making controlled inputs with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I've been trying to find a solution to how to make a single onChange listener for different inputs and then pass all the info to the single RTK state.

So, basically, the listener has to collect information from every input and then pass it to the correspondending object key which is in the array.

My slice looks like this:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

// State

const initialState = [
  {
    id: uniqid(),
    course: '',
    university: '',
    fromEd: '',
    toEd: '',
    descriptionEd: '',
  },
];

const educationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'education',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addEducation: (state) => {
      state.push({
        id: uniqid(),
        course: '',
        university: '',
        fromEd: '',
        toEd: '',
        descriptionEd: '',
      });
    },
    removeEducation: (state, action) => {
      state.splice(action.payload, 1);
    },
    updateEducation: (state, action) => {
      ------> ??? <-----
    },
  },
});

export default educationSlice.reducer;
export const { addEducation, removeEducation, updateEducation } =
  educationSlice.actions;
```

And my components looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateEducation } from '../../features/educationSlice';

function Education() {
  const education = useSelector((state) => state.education);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleEducationChange = (???) =>
    dispatch(updateEducation(???));

  return education.map((el, index) => (
    <span key={index}>
      <h3 className='form-header'>Education</h3>
      <input
        onChange={handleEducationChange}
        value={el.course}
        className='form-input'
        type='text'
        name='course'
        placeholder='Course / Program'
      />
      <input
        onChange={handleEducationChange}
        value={el.university}
        className='form-input'
        type='text'
        name='university'
        placeholder='University'
      />
      <input
        onChange={handleEducationChange}
        value={el.fromEd}
        className='form-input'
        type='text'
        name='fromEd'
        placeholder='Start Date'
      />
      <input
        onChange={handleEducationChange}
        value={el.toEd}
        className='form-input'
        type='text'
        name='toEd'
        placeholder='End Date'
      />
      <input
        onChange={handleEducationChange}
        value={el.descriptionEd}
        className='form-input'
        type='text'
        name='descriptionEd'
        placeholder='Description'
      />
      ...
```

Comment: You can read the `name` attribute from the input that triggered the change handler by accessing `changeEvent.currentTarget.name` (it's either currentTarget or target that let's you access the DOM element). It also helps to add the array index to the inputs, as a data-attribute for example. Then you know which element in `education` is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. all you have to set the event in the onChange to your function.

`<input
        onChange={(e) => handleEducationChange(e)}
        value={el.course}
        className='form-input'
        type='text'
        name='course'
        placeholder='Course / Program'
      />`

when you import the event in the function argument you can use e.target.value to get the user input into the dispatch function. see example for handler function.

`const handleEducationChange = (e) =>
    dispatch(updateEducation(e.target.value));`

your createslice need to get the input from the event and set it in the redux state. Your input will be the payload inside of the action object. You set it by using = to whatever state variable you want.

`updateEducation: (state, action) => {
     state.course = action.payload
    }`

This completes the circle. recap:

1. You make sure you get the `event.target.value` from the input component and pass that to the handler function.
2. Pass the `event.target.value` to the dispatch action.
3. Set state using `action.payload` in createslice. Your input data will be stored in the action.payload.

goodluck!